# Get current host in XmlAdapter

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, xmladapter

Is there a way of retrieving the current base URI in an XmlAdapter? Or how is this usually archieved?

```
public class Service{
...
    @GET
    public MyEntity getEntity() {
        return em.find(MyEntity.class, "dummy");
    }
...
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "myEntity")
public class MyEntity {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyAdapter.class)
    private Entity2 entity2Ref;
...

}



public class MyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Entity2Ref, Entity2> {

// Is NULL but shold be injected with host URI
@Context
UriInfo uri;

...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is a complete example of how this could be done:

### XML Response

Below I am going to demonstrate how to get the following response where the URI in the `address` element is put in via an `XmlAdapter` that is aware of the `UriInfo`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer id="1">
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <address>http://localhost:9999/address/123</address>
</customer>
```

### Java Model

Below is the Java model that I will use for this example.

**Customer**

By default the contents of the `Address` class will be marshalled beneath the `customer` element.  We will use an `XmlAdapter` to perform special handling for this.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"name", "address"})
public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AddressAdapter.class)
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

**Address**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Address {

    private int id;

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

### XmlAdapter

Below is the `XmlAdapter` that we will use.  Notice how it gets information from the `AddressResource` for building the `URI`.  It requires a `UriInfo`, this makes it stateful.  We will need to set an instance of this `XmlAdapter` on the `Marshaller` to get everything to work correctly.

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class AddressAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Address> {

    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    public AddressAdapter() {
    }

    public AddressAdapter(UriInfo uriInfo) {
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public Address unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Address v) throws Exception {
        if(null == uriInfo) {
            return "";
        }
        UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromResource(AddressResource.class);
        System.out.println(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().getHost());
        builder.scheme(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().getScheme());
        builder.host(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().getHost());
        builder.port(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().getPort());
        builder.path(AddressResource.class, "get");
        return builder.build(v.getId()).toString();
    }

}
```

### JAX-RS Services

In this example there are two services one for `Address` and another for `Customer`.

**AddressResource**

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Path("/address")
public class AddressResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Address get(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setId(id);
        return address;
    }

}
```

**CustomerResource**

Since we have a stateful `XmlAdapter` we can't just leverage JAXB through the default binding.  Instead we can access JAXB through a `StreamingOutput`.

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

@Provider
@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerResource {

    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    public CustomerResource() {
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO - Handle Exception
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public StreamingOutput get(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @PathParam("id") int id) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(id);
        customer.setName("Jane Doe");

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setId(123);
        customer.setAddress(address);

        return new MyStreamingOutput(jaxbContext, customer, uriInfo);
    }

}
```

### StreamingOutput

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class MyStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {

    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private Object object;
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    public MyStreamingOutput(JAXBContext jc, Object object, UriInfo uriInfo) {
        this.jaxbContext = jc;
        this.object = object;
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException {
        try {
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setAdapter(new AddressAdapter(uriInfo));
            marshaller.marshal(object, os);
        } catch(JAXBException jaxbException) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(jaxbException);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see how the linked answer can help me to inject the current host-uri in my XmlAdapter....

Comment: @JohannesStaehlin - I have just massively edited my answer with a complete example.  I hope this helps.